# Does Ext 3.2 have button icons?

Tags: extjs

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/button/buttons.html

I saw this and was wondering if I have access to these kind of icons for my itemCl config option.

Comment: also try the famfamfam silk icons if you want to have a lot of choice for button icons. the're free and very nice http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/silk/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Those specific images are in the `ext_base_dir/examples/button/images` directory.

Comment: Seems that the examples have migrated since this posted. In the 5.1 distro, there are icons at .../examples/kitchensink/resources/images/icons/fam